# Can a blockchain such as Ethereum grow "physically" too big?

Tags: storage, scalability

If a blockchain can be downloaded and verified by any node, wouldn't it get too big in storage size eventually? Ethereum only carries bytecode for smart contracts as additional information (please correct me if wrong), and it's already tens of GBs. I can totally imagine it would discourage people from participating if the size grows over 1T.

Additionally, if some other blockchains are used to be share bigger contents such as pictures and videos, how would that scale and still stay decentralized.

Comment: That's why we are working on sharding. Also contents should not be stored on chain but on a side decentralised storage and only the address and signature of the content is stored on the chain.